# Why is my function not grabbing the values from a blank input box and executing the function correct?

Tags: javascript

In my program, I wrote several functions so that when you typed any number of ticket holders and complementary passes from 1 to 550, and after that, when you clicked on the button "Calculate Available Seats", it would display : "The number of available seats is " and then 555 minus the number of ticket holders and complementary passes. However, with my current code, when I finish typing into the two blank boxes with two random numbers, and then I click on the button "Calculate Available Seats", it always returns "The number of available seats is 555". I want the program to first subtract the two values of ticket holders and passes from 555(the maximum number of seats on that plane) and display that value, not just 555.

```js
    var TicketHolders = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtTickets").value) || 0;
    var ComplementaryPasses = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtPasses").value) || 0;
    
    function number_of_available_seats(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses) {
      var answer = 555 - (TicketHolders + ComplementaryPasses);
     return("The number of available seats is " + answer);
    }
    var button = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
    
    
    
    function showresults(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses) {
     document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = number_of_available_seats(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses);
    }
    
    function clickonbutton(){
    showresults(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses);
    }
    
    button.onclick = function() {
    clickonbutton();
    };
```

```html
    <!-- airbus.html -->
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Airbus Seat Calculator</title>
    <style>
    DIV.movable { position:absolute;}
    </style>
    
    </head>
     
    <body>
    
      <h2>Airbus Seat Calculator</h2>
     
      <form id="formTest" method="get" action="processData">
        <table>
        
        <tr>
          <td><label for="txtTickets">Ticket Holders<span class="inputs"></span></label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtTickets" name="tickets"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="txtPasses">Complementary Passes<span class="inputs"></span></label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtPasses" name="passes"></td>
        </tr>
        
        
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
              <input type="button" value="Calculate Available Seats" id="btnSubmit"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    
    <div id="results"> 
    </div>
    <h2>Your Copyright Info Goes Here</h2>
    <script src="airbus.js">
    
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
var TicketHolders = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtTickets").value) || 0;
var ComplementaryPasses = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtPasses").value) || 0;
```

at the top of your script. It's only called once, so it's only calculated once (On the page load). Simply moving it down into the `clickonbutton` function, you will get the values when the button is clicked:

```js
    function number_of_available_seats(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses) {
      var answer = 555 - (TicketHolders + ComplementaryPasses);
     return("The number of available seats is " + answer);
    }
    var button = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
    
    
    
    function showresults(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses) {
     document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = number_of_available_seats(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses);
    }
    
    function clickonbutton(){
      var TicketHolders = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtTickets").value) || 0;
    var ComplementaryPasses = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtPasses").value) || 0;
    showresults(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses);
    }
    
    button.onclick = function() {
    clickonbutton();
    };
```

```html
<!-- airbus.html -->
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Airbus Seat Calculator</title>
    <style>
    DIV.movable { position:absolute;}
    </style>
    
    </head>
     
    <body>
    
      <h2>Airbus Seat Calculator</h2>
     
      <form id="formTest" method="get" action="processData">
        <table>
        
        <tr>
          <td><label for="txtTickets">Ticket Holders<span class="inputs"></span></label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtTickets" name="tickets"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="txtPasses">Complementary Passes<span class="inputs"></span></label></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="txtPasses" name="passes"></td>
        </tr>
        
        
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
              <input type="button" value="Calculate Available Seats" id="btnSubmit"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    
    <div id="results"> 
    </div>
    <h2>Your Copyright Info Goes Here</h2>
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```